# Assign values from list to specific values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, reference, variable-assignment

I have list of values:

```
list = [value1, value2, value3]
```

And a list of dictionaries where on specific keys I must set the corresponding values:

```
dictionaries = [{"key1":{"key2":{"key3":position_value1}}},{"key1":{"key2":{"key3":position_value2}}}]
```

I'm trying to assign the values avoiding solutions that requires do explicit iteration over the numerical indexes of list and dictionaries.

> I find the next pseudo-solution iterating over two iterables at the same time using for-each loops

```
for (dict, value) in zip(dictionaries, list):
    dict['key1']['key2']['key3'] = value
print(dictionaries)
```

But doesn't work due to, all dictionaries take only the last value of the list of values, obtaining the next result:

```
[{"key1":{"key2":{"key3":position_value3}}},{"key1":{"key2":{"key3":position_value3}}}]
```

It's important to note that when creating the list of dictionaries the dict.copy() method  was used, but maybe this doesn't take affect in the reference allocated in nested dictionaries.

> Dictionary list creation

```
base_dict = {"key1": {"key2":{"key3": None}}}
dictionaries = [base_dict.copy() for n in range(3)]
```

I appreciate any compact solution, even solutions based on unpacking.

Comment: Show code for how you created the list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
base_dict = {"key1": {"key2":{"key3": None}}}
dictionaries = [base_dict.copy() for n in range(3)]
```

Will create *shallow* copies of `base_dict`. That means that while these are indepenedent at the top level, their values are copied by reference; hence, the inner dictionaries `{"key2":{"key3": None}}` are still all the same object. When rebinding `key3`, all references will be affected.

You can avoid that by making a [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
from copy import deepcopy

dictionaries = [deepcopy(base_dict) for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: As long as `base_dict` is simple and used only once a good alternative would be `[{"key1": {"key2":{"key3": None}}} for _ in range(3)]`